# How do I move the close and maximise buttons in gnome shell?

Tags: gnome, customization, window-buttons

I would like my window buttons to be elementary like with the close button on the left and maximise on the right with no minimise button. Gnome Tweak Tool seems to only allow me to move all buttons, not individual buttons. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't have gconf-editor: install it by this command

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

After installing:

1. Press `ALT + F2` to bring Dash command window
2. Type  `gconf-editor` in that window
3. After opening gconf-editor, Go to `appps --> metacity --> general`
4. Change the **button_layout** option to this value `menu,close:maximize`
5. Close the gconf-editor.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a close button on left and a maximize button on right of the title bar, Do this:

1. Open a terminal by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Then write this command below and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout 'close:maximize'
   ```

You're done. Here is a screenshot of the Opera browser window:

[image]